# Eclipse setup Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: eclipse, development-environment, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to setup Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04. I have installed Eclipse SDK 3.5.2 from the Synaptic Package manager. 
The problem is, Eclipse is not giving me an option to create Java or Dynamic Web Projects. It also does not properly recognize the projects that I import (shows source folders but not packages). 
**Do I have the right version of Eclipse or do I need to install anything besides this.**
Please note that I already have Sun's JVM set as the default for my system. Have been trying for a while and have searched everywhere with no luck, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version packaged in Ubuntu is a light version for Java SE development (i.e. standalone java application). If you want to create web projects, you need a version with a lot more plugins. [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.. [Here it is](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2).